# How does Soundcloud API with pagination work?

Tags: ruby, json, api, pagination, soundcloud

I used the code given via SoundCloud:

[image]

This is the error in my terminal results read:

[image]

I can't figure out what I did wrong.. :\

This is the result of when I type just "puts tracks"

[image]

You can see where the next_href is displayed at the bottom.

Comment: can you provide more information about `tracks`? add the output of doing `puts tracks` and/or `puts tracks.each {|t| puts t}`

Comment: Im about to work on that... @MikeSlutsky

Comment: So I added what the results look like when i write "puts track" and when i write "puts track.each..." @MikeSlutsky

Comment: Please do not paste images of text.  Rather, paste the text itself.  You will be able to format the text as code.  It'll look good, and it will be a lot friendlier to those who want to try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the data returned, it might be that it is in a sub-property called "collection", so the correct iterator is "tracks.collection.each"

Comment: hmm..ok thanks, i'll check it, did/do you have trouble with pagination via soundcloud api? @nickf

Comment: ...and nope, it called collection an undefined method :\

Comment: any other advice @nickf ?